# Getting 'The name 'LoginScreen' isn't a class' error despite creating the class and importing required packages

Tags: flutter, dart, supabase

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I've been facing an issue for a while now and I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting the following error: "The name 'LoginScreen' isn't a class. Try correcting the name to match an existing class." I have already created the class in a separate file and imported all the necessary packages, including material.dart.
Here's a simplified version of my code:

**Main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  //load env
  await dotenv.load();
//initiliase supabase
  String supabaseurl = dotenv.env['SUPABASE_URL'] ?? '';
  String supabasekey = dotenv.env['SUPABASE_KEY'] ?? '';
  await Supabase.initialize(url: supabaseurl, anonKey: supabasekey);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const LoginScreen());
  }
}
```

**Login_screen.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginScreen> createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: Text("Login Screen")),
    );
    //return Container();
  }
}
```

Despite having the LoginScreen class defined in the login_screen.dart file and properly imported in main.dart, the error still persists when attempting to instantiate LoginScreen as the home widget in MyApp.

I have already double-checked the following points:

The file name and class name are spelled correctly, both with proper casing.
The required packages, such as material.dart, are imported correctly.
I'm using Flutter with Dart, and any help in identifying the root cause of this error would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

If additional code or information is needed, please let me know, and I'll provide it promptly.

-Mauz

Answer (score 2):

You need to import login_screen.dart into main.dart to use the widget.

Depending on your file structure, you can do this in a few ways.

If login_screen.dart and main.dart are in the same folder (e.g. 'lib), you can just add:

```
import 'login_screen.dart';
```

to the top of main.dart

If they are in different folders, you need to specify the path. For example, if login_screen.dart is in a 'screens' folder, your import would be:

```
import 'screens/login_screen.dart';
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much. This makes a lot more sense. 
I am new to dart and I thought it would find the files if they all in the same directory or subdirectory.